# Leap Motion and Chrome Security

Tags: google-chrome, socket.io, openssl, leap-motion

I'm developing a Chrome application using node, video via WebRTC, and Leap Motion functionality via socket.io and testing it locally.
Before the Chrome Security updates (version 46 and earlier) my LM controller and rigged hand functionality worked fine. 
Now, after I implemented a secure HTTPS connection generating my own keys via OpenSSL to comply with Chrome security, my controller no longer works. I receive the error (both occur in leap.js):

```
 WebSocket connection to 'wss://<myIP>:6436/v6.json' failed: Error in connection establishment: net:: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://<myIP>:2013/expert.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://<myIP>:6437/v6.json'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

Other functionality that depends on websocket.io (drawing tool, freeze tool, etc.) functions properly, so this leads me to believe that my error is something that I need to address with Chrome itself.

Any insights are appreciated!

Comment: Fix `v6.json`; don't allow it to make HTTP requests. Also see [How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content) from the Mozilla Developer Network. Its kind of lame, though. It does not tell you how to identify the object that's causing mixed content (i.e., what is being fetched over HTTP rather than HTTPS). That's really all we are interested in, so I'm not sure why they don't provide clear and concise steps to determine the offender.

Comment: Cross reference to some troubleshooting techniques: https://community.leapmotion.com/t/leap-motion-and-chrome-security/4773